# PHP "No such file or directory" - but it should be there

Tags: php, include

I just got a strange problem. I am including some files from my index.php, and now I got this error:

```
 require(cfg/cfg.database.inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...\index.php on line XX
```

Strange is that it worked just a minute ago. I double checked the spelling of that filename.

What I did: I am using Notepad++ and I saw my code like this:

```
require("cfg/cfg.database.inc.php" );
```

I wanted to remove the space between `"` and `)`, so i moved the cursor there and pushed Del, but it deleted the last `p` of `.php`.

I deleted the whole line and rewrote it, and now I get the error that the file cannot be found. I also renamed the file which is not working. All files in the subdir `cfg` get this error, but not those in other subdirs.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong or what I can do to find the problem?
*Thanks.*

/edit: My file structure

```
index.php
cfg/cfg.database.inc.php
cfg/cfg.other.inc.php
core/class.user.inc.php
core/...
```

All includes in `core` work, none of those from `cfg`

Comment: What does var_dump(glob('cfg/*')); return?

Comment: If you had weird character behavior, have you tried checking the document in an hex editor? (possibly adding it to Notepad++ with http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/)

Comment: @Alan Storm: array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "cfg/cfg.database.inc.php" [1]=> string(24) "cfg/cfg.datetime.inc.php" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usualy two reasons for this kind of behavior

1. Your PHP file and/or your file name has a character that's rendering to the screen as a standard, ascii letter, but is in fact some other letter in another encoding
2. You have multiple cfg folders, and PHP is looking in the wrong one.

Give this s try to see which cfg folder (relative to your running script) PHP sees, and what files it sees in there.

```
$my_cfg_files = glob('./*');
```

Next, try requiring files by iterating the loop

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
foreach($my_cfg_files as $file)
{
    echo 'trying ' . $file . "\n";
    require_once($file);
}
exit("\n Done \n");
```

Take a look at the list of files that it outputs.  Copy what the scripts prints and include it in your require statement.

Comment: Seems like it was number 2. I renamed my file names, but I didn't keep the ".php" this time, like Windows Explorer suggested. Seems like there was some invisible character in it...

Answer (score 1):

> All files in the subdir cfg get this error, but not those in other subdirs.

Try:

```
require("cfg.database.inc.php");
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry. Can you explain why you think it should?

Comment: Because if you're already in cfg, then cfg/cfg.database.inc.php would be cfg/cfg/cfg.database.inc.php

Can you also try require("/cfg/cfg.database.inc.php"); ?

Comment: No I am in /, and none of your suggestions works. I think there is some invisible character or something stupid like that...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a space:

```
require("cfg.database.inc.php   ");
```

Remove it:

```
require("cfg.database.inc.php");
```